# Ajax getting response undefined and Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: php, jquery

Code:

```
query = "http://localhost:8080/working_login.php?name=" + name + "&password=" + pass;
console.log(query);

   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: query,
 dataType: "script",
 success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log("success");
        },
error:function (msg) {
            console.log("error on page");
        }           
    });
```

I am getting undefined in data and as I am returning 'valid_user' from the server side made in php, getting error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: valid_user is not defined
 (anonymous function)
```

Php server side code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE name ='$name' AND password = '$password';"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Can not Register user' . $sql );
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rows > 0)
{ 
echo("valid_user");
exit();
}
else
{exit("not valid user");}
```

Comment: Why are you using the `script` data type, if you're not returning a valid script?

Comment: @DCoder So what I should use? As when I use script it comes in success else it goes on error on page.

Comment: show us what the server sends back

Comment: I usually return a JSON object with a `status` property indicating success or error, plus any extra data needed.

Comment: @DCoder I have added the code for server side

Comment: Which doesn't return JSON either.

Comment: FYI anyone will be able to hack in because you're not preventing SQL injection. What if I put ' OR '1'='1 as my password your SQL says ...AND password = '' OR '1'='1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using the script dataType in the jquery ajax reqeust, the returned result is interpreted as javascript code, but you return plain text

simply change `dataType: "script"` to `dataType: "text"`.

Comment: oh sure, forgot there also is a text type... updated the answer

Comment: @AndreasLinden ok let me check again.

Comment: if it sill does not work, just remove the `dataType` from the ajax request. it will then automatically determine the best fitting type.

Comment: Yes, XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/working_login.php?name=kamil&password=abc. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
error on page

Comment: this is cross-site-scripting-prevention. you can only ajax-request targets on the same domain. maybe change the query to `/working_login.php?name=kamil&password=abc.`

Comment: @AndreasLinden So what should I do now?

Comment: No, I am just simply running it, not from the locahost:8080

Comment: so this cannot work. you must run the javascript also on localhost:8080

Comment: you're doing something else wrong then. you should describe your problem better...

Comment: Just did what @AndreasLinden told and removed the Header tag from php code

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't mean to tell jQuery that you were expecting a script in return. What's being returned isn't a properly formatted script, so it's giving you an error when the browser parses as a script.

You could just do the following:

```
$.get("http://localhost:8080/working_login.php?name=" + name + "&password=" + pass, function(data) {
    if(data == 'success')
    {
        alert("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Failed");
    }
});
```